# Show wrapper divs if query has results, then loop the results

Tags: php

I'm trying to, in the second query in the following code, only show the wrapper div for the query results if there are any results, then loop over the results in a list after showing the wrapper divs.

However, I'm getting a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' on line 59`. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
// Creating the widget
class wpb_box extends WP_Widget {
function __construct() {
parent::__construct(
// Base ID of your widget
'wpb_box',
// Widget name will appear in UI
__('ابزارک اختصاصی باکس مطالب', 'bigtheme'),
// Widget description
array( 'description' => __( 'ابزارک اختصاصی نمایش باکس مطالب دسته های مختلف در صفحه اصلی سایت', 'bigtheme' ), )
);
}
// Creating widget front-end
// This is where the action happens
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        $name = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['name'] );
        $link1 = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['link1'] );
$link = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['link'] );
        $display = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['display'] );
        $color = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['color'] );
// This is where you run the code and display the output
?>
                    <article class="container-fluid">
                        <h5 style="background:<?php echo $color ?>;"><a href="<?php echo $link ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $name ?></a></h5> 
                        <?php  
            $portfolio = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_status' =>'publish',
            'post_type' =>'post',
            'cat' =>''.$link1.'',
            'posts_per_page' =>'1',
            'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1
            )); if($portfolio->have_posts()) : while($portfolio->have_posts()) : $portfolio->the_post(); ?> 
                        <div class="first-post col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumb',array( 'class'=> "img-responsive")); ?></a>
                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        </div>  
                        <?php endwhile; endif;  wp_reset_query(); ?>
                        <?php  
            $portfolio = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_status' =>'publish',
            'post_type' =>'post',
            'cat' =>''.$link1.'',
            'offset' => '1',
            'posts_per_page' =>''.$display.'',
            'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1            
            )); if($portfolio->have_posts()) : while($portfolio->have_posts()) : $portfolio->the_post(); ?> 
                        <div class="other-post col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <ul style="color:#f0ad4e;">
                            <?php if($portfolio->have_posts()) : while($portfolio->have_posts()) : $portfolio->the_post();?>
                                <li><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></li>
                            <?php endwhile; endif;  wp_reset_query(); ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </article>
<?php
echo $args['after_widget'];
}
public function form( $instance ) {
        $name   = ( isset( $instance[ 'name' ] ) ) ? $instance[ 'name' ] : '';
        $link1  = ( isset( $instance[ 'link1' ] ) ) ? $instance[ 'link1' ] : '';
$link   = ( isset( $instance[ 'link' ] ) ) ? $instance[ 'link' ] : '';
        $color  = ( isset( $instance[ 'color' ] ) ) ? $instance[ 'color' ] : '';
        $display    = ( isset( $instance[ 'display' ] ) ) ? $instance[ 'display' ] : '';
?>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'color' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'رنگ باکس مطالب:' ); ?></label>
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'color' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'color' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $color ); ?>" placeholder="مثال : #CCC , #dd3333 , black , blue" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'name' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'عنوان باکس:' ); ?></label>
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'name' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'name' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $name ); ?>" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'link1' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'دسته بندی مطلب' ); ?></label>
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'link1' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'link1' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $link1 ); ?>" />
            </p>
<p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'link' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'لینک آرشیو' ); ?></label>
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'link' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'link' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $link ); ?>" />
            </p>

            <p>
                <label><?php _e( 'نمایش توضیحات مطالب' ); ?></label>
                <select class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'display' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'display' ); ?>">
                    <option <?php selected( $instance['display'], 'block'); ?> value="block">بله</option> 
                    <option <?php selected( $instance['display'], 'none'); ?> value="none">خیر</option> 
                </select>
            </p>

<?php
}
// Updating widget replacing old instances with new
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['name'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['name'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['name'] ) : '';
        $instance['link1'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['link1'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['link1'] ) : '';
$instance['link'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['link'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['link'] ) : '';
        $instance['link2'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['link2'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['link2'] ) : '';
        $instance['link3'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['link3'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['link3'] ) : '';
        $instance['link4'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['link4'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['link4'] ) : '';
        $instance['link5'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['link5'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['link5'] ) : '';
        $instance['color'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['color'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['color'] ) : '';
        $instance['display'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['display'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['display'] ) : '';
        $instance['source'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['source'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['source'] ) : '';
        $instance['time'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['time'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['time'] ) : '';
        return $instance;
    }
} // Class wpb_box ends here
// Register and load the widget
function wpb_box() {
register_widget( 'wpb_box' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_box' );
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query was built up a little incorrectly - expanded and indented, it looks like this:

```
if ($portfolio->have_posts()) :
    while($portfolio->have_posts()) :
        $portfolio->the_post(); ?> 
        <div class="other-post col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <ul style="color:#f0ad4e;">
                <?php
                if($portfolio->have_posts()) :
                    while($portfolio->have_posts()) :
                        $portfolio->the_post();
                        ?>
                        <li><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></li>
                <?php endwhile; endif;  wp_reset_query(); ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

You're starting the last query twice. I think what you're trying to do is to only show the `other-post`-div when there are results for the second query, and then loop through them to make a list of the titles for the other posts. Here's how you can achieve that:

```
if ($portfolio->have_posts()): ?> 
    <div class="other-post col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <ul style="color:#f0ad4e;">
        <?php while($portfolio->have_posts()) : $portfolio->the_post();?>
            <li><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif;  wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Essentially what this does is check whether the query returns any results - if it does, show the container divs and create the while-loop to show the actual posts in the list.

Here's the full changed code (with proper indentation for readability):

```
<?php
// Creating the widget
class wpb_box extends WP_Widget {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            // Base ID of your widget
            'wpb_box',
            // Widget name will appear in UI
            __('ابزارک اختصاصی باکس مطالب', 'bigtheme'),
            // Widget description
            array( 'description' => __( 'ابزارک اختصاصی نمایش باکس مطالب دسته های مختلف در صفحه اصلی سایت', 'bigtheme' )
        ));
    }
    // Creating widget front-end
    // This is where the action happens
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        $name = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['name'] );
        $link1 = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['link1'] );
        $link = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['link'] );
        $display = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['display'] );
        $color = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['color'] );
        // This is where you run the code and display the output
        ?>
        <article class="container-fluid">
            <h5 style="background:<?php echo $color ?>;"><a href="<?php echo $link ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $name ?></a></h5> 
            <?php  
            $portfolio = new WP_Query(array(
                            'post_status' =>'publish',
                            'post_type' =>'post',
                            'cat' =>''.$link1.'',
                            'posts_per_page' =>'1',
                            'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1
            ));
            if($portfolio->have_posts()) : while($portfolio->have_posts()) : $portfolio->the_post(); ?> 
                <div class="first-post col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumb',array( 'class'=> "img-responsive")); ?></a>
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </div>  
            <?php endwhile; endif;  wp_reset_query(); ?>
            <?php  
            $portfolio = new WP_Query(array(
                            'post_status' =>'publish',
                            'post_type' =>'post',
                            'cat' =>''.$link1.'',
                            'offset' => '1',
                            'posts_per_page' =>''.$display.'',
                            'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1            
            ));
            if ($portfolio->have_posts()): ?> 
                <div class="other-post col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <ul style="color:#f0ad4e;">
                        <?php while($portfolio->have_posts()) : $portfolio->the_post();?>
                            <li><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></li>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            <?php endif;  wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </article>
        <?php
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    public function form( $instance ) {
        $name   = ( isset( $instance[ 'name' ] ) ) ? $instance[ 'name' ] : '';
        $link1  = ( isset( $instance[ 'link1' ] ) ) ? $instance[ 'link1' ] : '';
        $link   = ( isset( $instance[ 'link' ] ) ) ? $instance[ 'link' ] : '';
        $color  = ( isset( $instance[ 'color' ] ) ) ? $instance[ 'color' ] : '';
        $display    = ( isset( $instance[ 'display' ] ) ) ? $instance[ 'display' ] : '';
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'color' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'رنگ باکس مطالب:' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'color' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'color' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $color ); ?>" placeholder="مثال : #CCC , #dd3333 , black , blue" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'name' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'عنوان باکس:' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'name' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'name' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $name ); ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'link1' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'دسته بندی مطلب' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'link1' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'link1' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $link1 ); ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'link' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'لینک آرشیو' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'link' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'link' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $link ); ?>" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label><?php _e( 'نمایش توضیحات مطالب' ); ?></label>
            <select class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'display' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'display' ); ?>">
                <option <?php selected( $instance['display'], 'block'); ?> value="block">بله</option> 
                <option <?php selected( $instance['display'], 'none'); ?> value="none">خیر</option> 
            </select>
        </p>
        <?php
    }
// Updating widget replacing old instances with new
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['name'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['name'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['name'] ) : '';
        $instance['link1'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['link1'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['link1'] ) : '';
        $instance['link'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['link'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['link'] ) : '';
        $instance['link2'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['link2'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['link2'] ) : '';
        $instance['link3'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['link3'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['link3'] ) : '';
        $instance['link4'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['link4'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['link4'] ) : '';
        $instance['link5'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['link5'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['link5'] ) : '';
        $instance['color'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['color'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['color'] ) : '';
        $instance['display'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['display'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['display'] ) : '';
        $instance['source'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['source'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['source'] ) : '';
        $instance['time'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['time'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['time'] ) : '';
        return $instance;
    }
} // Class wpb_box ends here
// Register and load the widget
function wpb_box() {
register_widget( 'wpb_box' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_box' );
?>
```